# Changing activities with Intent on listview button

Tags: java, android, listview, android-intent, android-listview

In the application I am building I have 2 listviews with, among other elements, 2 buttons on every row, one for eliminating that row and the other to pass to another activity using an Intent.
I am detecting clicks on both buttons by setting click listeners on both buttons on the getView method of the Adapter class.
The first button was something I couldn't figure out, because I needed to identify in which listview the button was clicked and the position of the clicked row which I couldn't realize how to do.
The second one I thought would be easier since all I needed to do was Intents.
However I needed to call a method from the activity class (had to instance it) since I couldn't make Intents in a non-activity class.
This last one threw a NullPointerException.
Will post all code & logcat in a while, be right back, any possible help will be appreciated.

Comment: well im waiting on you bro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will need to see your code, but basically what worked for me for being able to call intents within the code of the adapter was to use the host activity.

Something like this:

```
 item_new = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.my_view);                                   
 Activity host = (Activity) item_new.getContext();
 Intent intent = new Intent(host, MyActivity.class);
 host.startActivity(intent);
```

If you post the code maybe I can give more details

Answer (score 0):

I'm not figure out the entire problem, but if you want to start an Activity from an Adapter you could simply pass the current activity to the adapter constructor (or cast the **getContext()** to Activity, if you used that as context of your adapter)

In a line of code:

Activity.class.cast(getContext()).startActivity(intent);